# Nightwatch test fails after file download

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

I have a test that fills out and then submits a form on one page, which triggers a new page to load in the current window and a file to auto-download. When I run the test I can see the form fill action, new page load, and file download run successfully. However, an assertion that follows immediately to check the current url always results in an error about not being able to access indexOf for null property. I added a console log in my test to debug:

```
client.url(function (result) {
        console.log (result);
    });
```

And the OUTPUT was:

```
INFO Request: GET /session/557d4250a4b1874daed3ec801e19b1b2/url 
 - data:   
 - headers:  {"Accept":"application/json"}
{ status: -1, value: null, errorStatus: '', error: '' }
```

What could cause url() to return null? Any suggestions on how to debug this further would be appreciated!

Versions:

```
selenium standalone server version: 2.53.1
chromedriver version: 2.29.461585
chrome version: 58.0.3029.96
```

Comment: what is the URL of the newly opened page? how is the navigation made (browser history / state / window location)? is it hash-based routing?

Comment: also, is it possible you have `start_session` set to `false`? if so, change it to `true` to allow `url()` to interact with the selenium server session.